# Mirror Folder in cloud storage to drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I have a quick question....is there a way to mirror or sync automatically folder from my bucket in Google Cloud Storage to lets say Google Drive? As soon as I upload a folder or file to my bucket, it will also be available in a Google Drive folder

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage and Google Drive are unrelated products. Google does not provide any connection between the two.